# Sharepoint 2013 Team Site Template not behaving as expected

Tags: 2013, site-template

My question is, can you create a number of team sites within a subsite of SharePoint 2013?
I have a subsite of template Project Site.  Can I create a number of team subsites within that Project subsite?

I did try the above, but when I select team site as subsite template, it creates the subsite, but only create Documents library, not the normal contents like 'Attendees', 'Agenda', ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything works as expected.

If you create a sub site with the template "Team Site" you will not get web parts like "Agenda". It will only provide this contents:

- Newsfeed
- Documents
- a notebook

If you select the template "Project Site" when creating a sub site you will get this contents:

- Project Summary
- Newsfeed
- Documents
- Tasks
- Calendar (not sure if this is in 2013 project template - it is in 2016)

There is no list "Attendees" in SharePoint 2013 site templates.

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with the different templates in SharePoint.